# Can I create a destructor-like function for a class that runs a browser in watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, irb, watir-webdriver

I know that in most test frameworks, there is a function to clean up. I have been running some tests from IRB, so I would like to build an automated clean up function (like a destructor). I have tried some of the finalize type functions but none of them closed the unneeded browser. Has anybody solved an issue like this one?

IRB looks like

```
d = Session.new
=> #<Session:0x1016c5e60 @browser=#<Watir::Browser:0x1016c5dc0 url="http://ipchicken.com/" title="IP Chicken - Whats my IP address? ip address lookup"
d.do_something_test
your test passed!
=> nil
d = nil
=> nil
```

With the example class like

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
class Session
  attr_accessor :browser
  def initialize
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
    @browser.goto 'http://ipchicken.com'
  end

  def do_something_test
    puts "your test passed!" if @browser.html.match /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/
  end
end
```

Or maybe I am approaching this all wrong!? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use cucumber for example? I'm doing that for my project. 
Benefits:

- Nice DSL for features descriptions
- with rspec, nice matchers like @browser.url.should match "google.com"
- Continuous running
- features isolating

A small HowTo from my project, I just created a separate project with cucumber features only:

Testing project structure:

```
|-- config.yml
|-- features
|   |-- login.feature
|   |-- signup.feature
|   |-- profile.feature
|   |-- ...
|   |-- step_definitions
|   |   |-- auth_steps.rb
|   |   `-- click_steps.rb
|   |-- support
|   |   |-- dom.rb
|   |   |-- env.rb
|   |   `-- path.rb
|-- Gemfile
`-- Gemfile.lock
```

My Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "firewatir"
gem "watir-webdriver"
gem "awesome_print"

gem "cucumber"
gem "cucumber-rails"
gem "rspec"
gem "rspec-core"
gem "rspec-expectations"
gem "rspec-mocks"
```

env.rb

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'time'

Before do
  @config = YAML.load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../config.yml'))["test"]
  @@browser ||= case @config["browser"]
    when "firefox"
      require 'firewatir'
      FireWatir::Firefox.new
    when "IE"
      require 'watir'
      Watir::Browser.new
    when "Opera"
      require 'operawatir'
      OperaWatir::Browser.new
    when "Safari"
      require 'safariwatir'
      Watir::Safari.new
    when "Chrome"
      require 'watir-webdriver'
      Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
    end
end

at_exit do
  @@browser.close
end
```

If you will need more descriptions I will update the answer.

Update: As you can see Before creates browser and at_exit closes it. That works on windows as well BTW

Comment: Much thanks Stanislav. I have a test framework solution (I am doing it with RSpec), so I can close up nicely with a after :all. But I am working with IRB a great deal too and forgot to close the browser before the new session (dangling process). I would prefer to kill it in a destructor if possible. But the info is very helpful (because I don't know much about proper project structure).